# Setter functions in angular providers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

From my understanding factories are an abstraction over Angular's providers, which allow you to return data with less lines of code. However, providers provide more flexibility in that you can better define the service's functionality. I'm still really confused on how to call a simple function from a provider. Everyone seems to be doing them differently and I cannot get mine to work:

```
myApp.provider('myProvider', function() {
    myVar = true;

    $get: function() {
        return {
            myVar: myVar,
        }
    },

    toggleFalse = function() {
        myVar = false;
    },
})

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, myProvider) {
    myProvider.toggleFalse();
});
```

This does not seem to work - and I'm having trouble understanding services in general. It says `toggleFalse` is not defined. How do you properly define a setter function on an Angular service that can be controlled through a controller?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do.  You are creating a local function-scoped variable on the provider called 'myVar'.  You are creating a separate 'myVar' property on the returned object when the provider is injected.  Do you want to have one global value shared by all instances of the provider or do you want each to have their own value?

Comment: I'm looking to have one globally shared value. I didn't want to set a global variable because I thought there might be a way to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do `console.dir(myProvider)`, you'll see that you are getting the object returned from `$get`.  You need to put the function on the returned object:

```
$get: function() {
    return {
        myVar: myVar,
        toggleFalse: function() {
            myVar = false;
        },           
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple question of closure.

If you want every instance to have a unique everything, then store everything inside `$get`.

If you want the majority of the object to be unique, but have some methods or objects/arrays that every instance shares with each other, then define those in the function closure outside of `$get` and append them to the object returned *from* `$get`.

```
... ("myProvider", function () {
  var sharedValue = 19,
      sharedFunction = function () {
          sharedValue += 1;
          return shared value;
      };


  return {
      $get : function () {
          return {
              unique : 1,
              shared : sharedFunction
          };
      }
  };
```

This isn't an Angular issue, so much as a core piece of JS's behaviour, which happens to be inside of an Angular paradigm.